# Android: Do I need a permission?

Tags: android

I was looking at putting a wake lock in my app, but now I've noticed that it is deprecated to do it a certain way. I saw somewhere that I can do this:

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

This works like wake lock, so do I still need a permission for it?

EDIT:
I did more research, and WakeLock isn't deprecated, using FULL_WAKE_LOCK is...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html (Look at FULL_WAKE_LOCK in constants)

Comment: Wakelocks are not deprecated.

Comment: oh, well I'll have to look into that. Regardless of that, do I still need a permission?

Answer (score 0):

WakeLocks aren't deprecated, and while you technically wouldn't need the permission to do it this way it probably wouldn't be polite to keep the users screen visible and turned up without some kind of warning like the permission would give.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the deprecation, there is a difference between those methods for keeping the screen on. A full wake lock would keep the screen on and processor running even when the user switches to other applications. In order for it to stop you would need to release the Wake Lock. Using the WindowManager however will allow it to be handled by the OS making it much simpler for you and less likely that you will drain the end user's battery unnecessarily.